# Forcing input through validation check

Tags: c++, validation, input

We created a validation check so that input can only be alphabetical character. While it is working as intended, my friend and I both came across an odd symptom where you can force through the validation even though the code clearly (at least to us) would not allow them to.

Running the following code, then pressing [enter] or random junk about dozen time and entering unacceptable input such as **321-** would cause the program to quit validation. Is it some kind of inherent limit or did we miss a code?

Even after stripping down the code to bare validation caused the symptom, though it did seems to have different limit depending on machine. Some computer let it sneak by after 3-4 brute forcing, while c9.io withstood roughly a dozen.

My validation loop does look messy, but I experienced before on smaller for loop as well. Only similarities I 've noticed so far is getline()

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

//prototypes
void validateUserName(string &name);//validate name

//main function
int main()
{

    //initialize
    ifstream file;

    string username; //holds username which serve as file name


    //first prompt
    cout<< "Enter your name and press <ENTER>";
    getline(cin, username);

    //call functions
    validateUserName(username);
    //begin shutdown
    cout << "good-bye" << endl;
    cin.get();
}




void validateUserName(string &name){
    int errCount = 0;
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        errCount = 0;
        i=0;
        //go thru each character of the name to count non-alphabetic character
        while (name[i])
            {
            if ( !isalpha(name[i]) )
            errCount++;
            i++;
            }

        if (errCount > 0 || name.empty() )
        {
            //prompt user again alerting them of error
            cout << "Invalid entry, try again" << endl;
            getline(cin, name);
        }

    }
    while (errCount > 0 || name.empty() );//the validation loop doesn't end until user enters acceptable entry
    name+=".txt"; //appended file type
}
```

Comment: While I can't 100% say it's your problem, with `while (name[i])`, you are iterating until you hit a `\0`, not until the end of the string. So you could exit the loop on a non-empty string without testing all characters. You should  use `for(char s : name)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you come out of your second cin `name` is no longer empty. So the second condition is not met and you exit the main while loop. A quick fix would be to increment errCount in the final conditional:

```
if (errCount > 0 || name.empty() )
{
   errCount++;                                                                                                                                                   
   cout << "Invalid entry, try again" << endl;
   getline(cin, name);
}
```

While it was not part of your question I would suggest you use `string::size()` instead of checking for the null character. I don't think getline adds this, so you could possibly be dealing with undefined behavior.

```
void validateUserName(string &name)
{
    int errCount = 0;
    do
    {
        errCount = 0;
        //go thru each character of the name to count non-alphabetic character                                                                                                                              
        for (int i = 0; i < name.size() && !name.empty(); i++)
        {
            if ( !isalpha(name[i]) ) 
            {
                errCount++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (errCount > 0 || name.empty() )
        {
            errCount++;
            //prompt user again alerting them of error                                                                                                                                                      
            cout << "Invalid entry, try again" << endl;
            getline(cin, name);
        }

     }
    while (errCount > 0 || name.empty() );//the validation loop doesn't end until user enters acceptable entry                                                                                              

}
```